# Prevent tmux from becoming idle

Tags: tmux

I work with a cluster that terminates idle processes after they have been idle for 24 hours but I want to leave tmux sessions running for multiple days so that they are still there when I  come back to them.

Is there an easy way to make tmux wake up every two hours to prevent long spans of being idle? The only think I could think of was to write a script that executes an arbitrary tmux command every hour, e.g. `tmux ls` to see if that solves the problem, but I feel like there must be a more elegant way.

Comment: Cronjob is the best thing I can think of. Either that or (in a tmux session) run something like `while sleep 2h; do echo alive; done` (I'm assuming that will prod the pty subsystem and make tmux wake up; this assumption requires testing).

Comment: Or add clock to status bar and force it to update every so often -- http://superuser.com/questions/517402/force-update-for-tmux-status-bar

Comment: Why does this keep getting voted down? There is nothing wrong with the question. It turns out that Tom's solution works @TomHunt if you post your comment as a solution I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to wake tmux periodically, you can run the following in a tmux session:

```
while sleep 2h; do echo alive; done
```

Since tmux handles its sessions' terminals in its own code, this will wake it up to handle the output.